# I have been put under a question ban

Tags: support, post-ban

I don't understand why but I have been put under a question ban. None of my questions has got too much of down votes nor my questions are of low quality but every time I try to ask a question, a message states that "you have reached your question limit". Is there a limit on asking question? How can I get out of this ban? please help.
[image]

Comment: You asked: *Is there a limit on asking question?* 
Yes there is a limit. You can only ask 6 questions/day, 50 questions/month. For details see here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770 But unless you have deleted some of your questions, this is probably not the reason why you cannot post questions. (The last question of yours I see [in your profile](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/131389/snehil-sinha?tab=questions&sort=newest) is from July.)

Comment: Maybe you could add a screenshot to your post, showing what the notification exactly looks like. If you really are under a question ban, the message should read: *We are no longer accepting questions from this account.* See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans

Comment: I see 3 m.se users named SNEHIL SINHA. Is it that common a name in India, even with the caps lock? or do you have 3 accounts? I wonder if a question ban could have something to do with multiple accounts.

Comment: @Gerry: That seems unlikely, but I agree that it raises further questions here.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I have added the screenshot as requested by you sir.Now can you please sort out my problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I admit that 2 of the accounts named SNEHIL SINHA has been created by me.But I made the other account just because of the question ban.I could find no alternative of posting my doubts and related questions other than doing so.But I don't think so that it would be the reason for the question ban as I had been put under ban before I created the second account,not after it.And as far as the third account is concerned,it is not mine.

Comment: So, what did it say when you clicked on the link to the Help Center?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am surprised to inform that I have been put out of the ban.I don't know how this happened.Do you have any idea?

Comment: No idea - a mystery to me.

Comment: If the system prevents you from doing something, opening a new account to circumvent that is a gross violation of the community's trust. You should ***never*** open a second account for the sole purpose of doing something that you couldn't do with your regular account.

Comment: Have you a shared IP address? Something like: you access the site from the school's computer lab, or from your parents' office. If that is the case, it can be that others using the same IP address have posted enough questions to reach the limit. The check for the question limits is or was, if I recall correctly, by IP address, so one can "hit" the limit without asking questions oneself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I really regret for what I have done.Is there a way through which I can delete my second account?